# Chef: use knife upload to push a local version of a cookbook that has been modified & repurposed from supermarket

Tags: chef-infra, knife

So I cloned a cookbook from the chef supermarket but I do NOT want to use their versioning, however, it is important for us to be able to version entire cookbooks on our chef server.

I am trying to figure out how to do this and am having very little luck finding an answer... I just don't want every single cookbook to default to version 0.0.0.

This is what I see currently:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `version` setting of `metadata.rb` in the downloaded cookbook to your preferable version.

But if you want all of cookbooks you downloaded to be the version you want to control for any reason. You could probably iterate through all cookbooks and update version in metadata.rb programatically.

Comment: Thanks! that worked.. but do you know how to make sure that your readme is also sent to the chef server uppon running ```berks upload```?

Comment: I don't know offhand but  `long_description` might be what you want, for example: adding `long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.rdoc'))` in metadata.rb to get the content of `README.rdoc`